# Admob house ad mediation problems

Tags: ios, admob

did anyone had success with creating houseads in the new admob.

I have created a new campaign with those banners:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvl7tdx74j9xokt/blue.png

But the houseads are not showing up.

Mirza